How did the Soviets produce randomness with their one-time pads in WW2?
In literature is mentioned that the Soviets used a simple computer (e.g. In the Enemy House by Howard Blum, pag 43). The NSA Friedman archive on the Venona project does not disclose the method the Soviets used to create the one-time pads, except for their mistake to re-use some pages again, allowing the precursor of the NSA to decrypt a few thousands of cables.
In an earlier question in 2018 on how one-time pads and keys historically were generated Patriot answered "During the Cold War, the Soviets were known to generate one-time pads by having rooms full of typists peck away "randomly." That's not genuinely random, but still formidable because such results are--as another writer said--from different people and can be muddled further". This points to manual labor. David Kahn mentions the same in The Code Breakers on page 663: "One such pad, for example, has seven times as many groups in which digits in the 1-to-5 group alternate with digits in the 6-to-0 group, like 18293, as a purely random arrangement would have. This suggests that the typist is striking alternately with her left hand (which would type the 1-to-5 group on a Continental machine) and her right (which would type the 6-to-0 group). Possibly the girls, ordered to type at random, sensed that some doublets and triplets would occur in a random text but, misled by their conspicuousness, minimized them. Despite these anomalies, however, the digits still show far too little pattern to make cryptanalysis possible."
For the Soviets it was extremely important that those one-time pads were impossible to crack. Even when they were warned that the Americans could decrypt part of it, they did not change this method. The inventor was Vladimir A. Kotelnikov whose article (allegedly published in 1940 or maybe earlier) described the one-time pad and possibly how to produce, but is still hidden in the Russian archives.
Hence the question: how did the Russians realize true randomness, or something close to it in the war years. I am looking for historical papers documenting their practice as evidence.
